# Event notifications in multiclient environment

Tags: perl, events, queue

I'm using perl IMAP client which waits for IMAP idle events, and it works great.

I would like to queue these events as messages and offer them ASAP to the web clients, which should be able to read them from the queue or wait for new messages. Clients are also making decision which messages should be removed from the queue.

Is there a module which has this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Answering the IMAP-specific part of this question -- your suggestion that you'd like your webmail clients to "remove events from the queue" looks very supsicious. Make sure you understand the semantics of the IMAP because there are not many "events" which can be safely "removed" from there.

Comment: IMAP just tells that there is a change in inbox, and I want to record such event as message in some kind of queue. Instead of IMAP client there could also be anything that generate messages, so *messages* are removed from the queue. Tnx for correction.